# Как правильно заменить ссылку запросом в mysql?

Tags: mysql

Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно составить запрос. Нужно удалить ссылку из title.

```
UPDATE `content` SET `title` = REPLACE( `title`, '<a href="telnet://*">', '' ) ;
```

Вместо * разные IP адреса.

Answer (score 1):

Этот вопрос можно решить через регулярные выражения **[REGEXP](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-regexps.htm)** .

но лучше использовать **[lib_mysqludf_preg](https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_preg#readme)**

```
PREG_RLIKE( pattern , subject )
PREG_CAPTURE(pattern, subject [, capture-group] [, occurence] )
PREG_CHECK( pattern )
PREG_POSITION(pattern, subject [, capture-group] [, occurence] )
PREG_REPLACE(pattern, replacement, subject [ ,limit ] ) 
LIB_MYSQLUDF_PREG_INFO()
```

можете также попробовать с **[mysql-udf-regexp](https://github.com/hholzgra/mysql-udf-regexp)**

```
REGEXP_LIKE(text, pattern [, mode])
REGEXP_SUBSTR(text, pattern [,position [,occurence [,mode]]])
REGEXP_INSTR?(text, pattern [,position [,occurence [,return_end [,mode]]]])
REGEXP_REPLACE?(text, pattern, replace [,position [,occurence [,return_end [,mode]]])
```

Также можно использовать функции **[LEFT()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-string-functions.htm#function_left)**, **[RIGHT()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-string-functions.htm#function_right)** , **[SUBSTRING(str,pos,len)](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-string-functions.htm#function_substring)**

Comment: А без дополнительных бибилиотек или программ не получится? Чем можно заменить * в запросе?